# Read and write to dynamically allocated array

Tags: c

I have a text file containing a matrix N by 3 of float numbers. I need to read the matrix and put the data into a dynamically allocated array. I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define X_ 0
#define Y_ 0
#define Z_ 0
#define VERTEX_COUNT 3


void read_data(FILE* FILE_POINTER, float **GRID, int N_LINES)
{
int i = 0, j=0;

for(i = 0; i < N_LINES; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < VERTEX_COUNT; j++) 
  {
   if (!fscanf(FILE_POINTER, "%f", &GRID[i][j])) 
       break;
  }

}
}



int find_length(FILE* FILE_POINTER)
{
int ch = 0;
int length = 0;

if(FILE_POINTER != NULL)
{
    while(!feof(FILE_POINTER))
    {
        ch = fgetc(FILE_POINTER);
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            length++;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    perror("File not found");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} 
return length;
}



int main() 
{   
/* Define variables needed*/
int i=0,j=0;
float** GRID_GEOM;
float** GRID_TOPO;

/* Open the files containing the data*/
FILE* FILE_GEOM = fopen("temporary_geom.txt","r");
FILE* FILE_TOPO = fopen("temporary_topo.txt","r");

/* Find length of the data set*/
int N_POINTS = find_length(FILE_GEOM);
int N_TRIANG = find_length(FILE_TOPO);


/* Dynamically allocate memory for each data set*/
GRID_GEOM = malloc(N_POINTS * sizeof(float*));
for (i = 0; i < N_POINTS; i++)
{
    GRID_GEOM[i] = malloc(VERTEX_COUNT * sizeof(float));
}

GRID_TOPO = malloc(N_TRIANG * sizeof(float*));
for (i = 0; i < N_TRIANG; i++)
{
    GRID_TOPO[i] = malloc(VERTEX_COUNT * sizeof(float));
}

/* Read data into the arrays*/
read_data(FILE_GEOM, GRID_GEOM, N_POINTS);


/* Close the files */
fclose(FILE_GEOM);
fclose(FILE_TOPO);

/* Free the memory allocated */
for (i = 0; i < N_POINTS; i++) 
{
    free(GRID_GEOM[i]);
}
free(GRID_GEOM);

for (i = 0; i < N_TRIANG; i++) 
{
    free(GRID_TOPO[i]);
}
free(GRID_TOPO);
}
```

When I try to access any position in the matrix GRID_GEOM, all values seem to be 0. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why are you usin upper case for variables?  Lower case  is the norm. Also better names would be useful

Comment: Also try to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: Please provide some sample input and show what the "output" is (your code does not show at which point there are 0 values; did you check if any of the loops are actually entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `find_length`, you read the whole file so when you pass the file pointer to `read_data`, it already points to the end of it.

You can either [rewind the pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rewind.htm), or close the file and reopen it again for parsing data.